# How to get the original schema on SQL Server from SELECT that fills DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, schema

I have the following auxiliary function for loading `DataTable` based on SQL SELECT against a SQL Server database (a bit simplified):

```
static private DataTable GetData_(string connectionString, string sqlSelect, bool doFillSchema = false)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect, connection))
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        if (doFillSchema)
            adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Mapped);

        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
}
```

The later goal is to pass the returned `table` to another function that should export the content into a DBF table (that is to CREATE TABLE and write the content with some corrections related to different capabilities of the engines).

The problem is that the implementation changes the original say `numeric(10, 2)` column type into `Decimal` in the schema. I would like to preserve the original.

If I understand it well, I probably need to get another `DataTable schemaTable` with the original schema (before the column types get changed by by the adapter). My idea was to modify the function like that:

```
static private DataTable GetData_(string connectionString, string sqlSelect,
                                  bool doFillSchema, ref DataTable schemaTable)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect, connection))
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        if (doFillSchema)
            ??? fill the schema table

        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
}
```

How the functionality should be implemented? Should the `SqlDataAdapter` be used for the purpose? Or should it be done differently?

Answer (score 0):

So fare, I have this self-answer. If you have a better solution, I will be happy to accept it. ;)

```
static private DataTable GetData_(string connectionString, string sqlSelect, Hashtable arg,
                                  bool doFillSchema, ref DataTable schemaTable)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        // If we want the schema, do the extra step.
        if (doFillSchema)
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
                schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }

        // Use the adapter to fill the result table..
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            // Set the SELECT arguments.
            if (arg != null)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry item in arg)
                {
                    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value);
                }
            }

            // Get the result of the SQL query.
            adapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```